# Double slit experiment gun precision

Tags: double-slit-experiment

If instead of a gun that the progectile can go to either slit, if a long barrel, very precise shooting device, capable of consistently shooting 
thru one slit. 100 % . Now the two slits are set up and the long barrel
is aimed at only one slit. Does the presense of a second slit alter the pattern?

Comment: Yes it does, but in a minor way. The peak intensity will be where the gun is aimed. The lines of interference will be there, but very faint, because by pointing the gun you reduce the probability for particles to go through the other slit. The probability is never zero, but can be low.

Comment: The logical error here is in thinking that the gun shoots bullets. It doesn't. It shoots waves. And waves don't go 100% straight. This setup is no different from the waves on the surface of a lake. Rephrase your question in terms of waves on water and the answer becomes self evident.

Comment: a rifle barrel stabilizes the trajectory of the exiting bullet, but a wave emerging out of a long narrow pipe has a large transverse momentum uncertainty and spreads out quickly.

Comment: @lama the trick is to use a very wide barrel then, and short wavelength projectiles.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Who's "Lama"?

Answer (score 0):

The above comment by @safesphere has given the answer properly in terms of waves.
Here i am giving an explanation in terms of particle:
For a shooting particle, there are different probabilities of following the different paths from gun to the slit.
By pointing gun to left slit, you are only increasing the probability of particle for left path but it still have non zero probability for right path. And an ensemble of a single particle can therefore interfere with itself to give the interference pattern but the pattern will be shifted down depending on how much you are focusing the gun on left.